# Developing and deploying java application

Tags: java, deployment, development

I've been programming in Java for some time and was trying to develop something that I can 'deploy'. I search online for ways of bundling my java program(s) in installable "packages" but can't find any precise answer for it!

My search results returned something about [IBM CICS](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/signup.do?source=ITSO&S_PKG=ov1262), but before I go about reading the book I'd like to be sure I'm going the right way.

How are developers managing to make their Java applications installable? Some guidelines will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which IDE you're using. Here are the methods for Net beans and Eclipse;

Netbeans: https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

Eclipse: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbhJ9sTMTD8

Both are have to export them as a .JAR, which is a really easy way for other people to run the java application.

I have used the Eclipse method before for university - But i am not a user of Netbeans.

EDIT #1;

A program that can turn your .JAR/Java application into an installable program.

http://izpack.org/

Comment: but I don't want `.jar` files, I want to produce native installation steps, like the bunch of "next"s that Windows users have to go through :)

Comment: That's something I've not done before, Added a quick edit to my question with a link that might just be the answer.